# localStorage not getting cleared when system shutdown happens

Tags: javascript, angularjs, window, local-storage, onbeforeunload

I am using localStorage for sharing data across tabs. I need to clear the localStorage whenever the user closes the tab/browser. I am able to achieve that but the thing is if the user directly shutdowns the system or its a system forced shutdown then the localStorage is not getting cleared. Please suggest any solution for this.

I am using localStorage and not sessionStorage because I want to share data across tabs.

Comment: You basically can't rely on getting and processing an event when the user leaves your site. Frequently you'll get an `beforeunload`, but it's not guaranteed. So you have to code around it.

Answer (score 3):

You basically can't rely on getting and processing an event when the user leaves your site. Frequently you'll get an `beforeunload`, but it's not guaranteed. So you have to code around it.

> I need to clear the localStorage whenever the user closes the tab/browser

<s>Sounds like you want to use `sessionStorage` rather than `localStorage`.</s> *No, `sessionStorage` doesn't seem to be shared between tabs. Huh, I thought it was.*

<s>If for some reason you can't use `sessionStorage` instead of `localStorage`,</s> I'd suggest storing some kind of "last used" timestamp in your store, and if it's too old when your page next loads, clearing the data at that point.

Comment: Thanks Crowder. The issue with timestamp is if the user log ins to app and shutdowns the system then the timestamp wont be too old if he tries to log in as soon as the system is up.

Comment: @VishalGulati: That's true, but then, does it really matter? In that scenario, sounds like they're dealing with a crash or something and want to pick up where they left off anyway, no?

Comment: @Crowder: No i cant put a check on that. The shutdown and restart takes 3-5 mins. I cant clear data for just this much time of inactivity.

Comment: @VishalGulati: Right, so you put a longer limit on it than that and they pick up where they left off. What's the problem? Given the constraints, I don't know that you have other options.

Comment: @Crowder: Thing is i set timestamp on login. but after login the user may be inside app and doing his stuff. That doesnot mean that he is inactive and i cant just clear the data. The timestamp was just an indication of when he last logged in. he may be active for an hour or two in the app. I cant clear the same.

Comment: @VishalGulati: No, you update it regularly, of course, while the user is in the app. That way when you check on arrival, and it's quite out of date, you know that's because the app hasn't been running.

Comment: @VishalGulati: I don't do the chat thing when it relates to the answer. Also, I don't see what further there is to discuss. Have a timestamp. Keep it up to date. If it's markedly out of date when your app loads, clear and start fresh. Because you **can't** rely on clearing when the user leaves the app.

Answer (score 1):

sessionStorage, localStorage and Cookies all are used to store data on the client side. Each one has its own storage and expiration limit. sessionStorage: similar to localStorage but expires when the browser closed (not the tab). Cookie: stores data that has to be sent back to the server with subsequent requests.

Comment: I have to share data across tabs. sessionStorage is out of scope.. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Session storage will be more help if you want to clear the data.You can place data onto the sessionStorage object and that data persists for as long as that window (or tab) is open.

Comment: I have to share data across tabs. sessionStorage is out of scope.. Thanks anyways.